# Is importar a reflexive verb?

Tags: reflexivos

I am supposed to transform the following sentence to a grammatically correct one word by word but without changing those bold ones.

> Usted/importar/**todas**/el/**especies en peligro**.

What is wrong with this version, please?

> Te importa todas las especies en peligro.

Comment: Las especies en peligro = plural

Answer (score 4):

*Importar* works like *gustar*. In fact you can say that

> *importar* : *gustar* :: *to care* : *to like*

That is, *importar* relates to *gustar* in more or less the same way as English "to care" relates to "to like" (grammatically speaking).

It's not a reflexive (pronominal) verb. It has two arguments: the **person** who cares about something, and the **thing** that someone cares about. The thing is the grammatical subject, but it tends to be found after the verb, instead of before as usual. The person is an indirect object, or dative, and it tends to be before the verb instead of after. So the usual word is reversed (again, exactly as in *gustar*).

I guess that your example

> Usted/importar/todas/el/especies en peligro

is supposed to mean "you (formal) care about all the endangered species". In that case the correct sentence in Spanish would be

> *A usted le importan todas las especies en peligro.*

*A usted* and *le* refer to the same person, but this redundancy is grammatically compulsory in this case. Note that *usted* is a second person pronoun but it works like third person, therefore we use *le*, not *te*, to refer to it.

*Importan* is in the plural (*-n*) because the grammatical subject is *todas las especies en peligro*, which is plural. Don't let the unusual order fool you.

If you need to "translate" this into English, you could think of *importar* as equivalent to "to be important":

> *A usted le importan todas las especies en peligro.*
>   "To you are important all the endangered species."

Comment: I tried, but "A usted le importan todas las especies en peligro." is still not correct. Could importar mean import instead?

Comment: @xyxue Who or what is telling you that the phrase is still incorrect?

Comment: Maybe I'm completely misunderstanding the exercise but I can't think of any alternative sentence. If you have the solution but you don't understand how it works, please tell me so I can adjust the answer.

Comment: Have you tried 'Usted importa todas las especies en peligro'? Is a bit odd, because implies an import/export business with all the endangered species, but is still correct.